# Xampp и phpword на windows

Tags: php, zip, xampp, phpword

Отказывается работать phpword при создании файла на основе шаблона. Выдаёт ошибки

> Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip
>   object in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\phpword\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive.php on
>   line 200
>
> Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip
>   object in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\phpword\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive.php on
>   line 203
>
> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db\phpword\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive.php on line 162
>
> Fatal error: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\db\phpword\PhpWord\Shared\ZipArchive.php on line 163

Хотя если вызвать информацию о php, то указано, что zip установлен и работает.
С правами доступа к файлу тоже всё хорошо - удалил все права и дал полный доступ группе "Все" всей папке и вложенным папкам с файлами.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. К слову, на работе есть машина (Linux, apache, php), так там всё работает.

Код скрипта для примера (возникающие ошибки представлены выше)

```
<?php 
    //Начинаем работу с шаблоном
    require_once 'PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $tamplate=1;
    $template_path="templates/passport/passport".$tamplate.".docx"; //Путь к файлу-шаблону
    $document_name="passport.docx"; //Имя, под готорым файл будет сохранён на диск + под которым будут скачивать
    $save_path="saves/passport/"; //Куда сохранять

    $template = $phpWord->loadTemplate(realpath($template_path)); //Загружаем шаблон

    //Поиск-Замена
    $FIO='Александров Вадим Вадимович';
    $template->setValue('FIO', $FIO);

    //Сохраняем
    $file =$save_path.$document_name;
    $template->saveAS($file); //Сохраняем документ
?>
```

Comment: можно загрузить скрипт

Comment: @L.Vadim, дополнил вопрос